# After run liquibase script in Ubuntu get error but in windows work fine

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, liquibase

I trying run liquibase script on Ubuntu terminal and I get error:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Table 'database.batch_job_execution' doesn't exist [Failed SQL: CREATE INDEX JOB_START_STATUS ON database.batch_job_execution(STATUS, START_TIME)]
```

For run script on Ubuntu terminal I use this code:

```
export LIQUIBASE_HOME=/home/bok/Liquibase
java -jar liquibase.jar \
      --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
      --classpath=mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar \
      --changeLogFile="dbchangelog.xml" \
      --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database" \
      --username=root \
      --password=password \
      update
```

On Windows OS this is script work fine. For run in Windows I create `*.bat` file from this code:

```
set LIQUIBASE_HOME=D:\work\liquibase
java -jar liquibase.jar 
    --logLevel=DEBUG 
    --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  
    --classpath=mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar 
    --changeLogFile="D:\dbchangelog.xml"
    --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database"  
    --username=root 
    --password=root 
    update
pause
```

I using MySQL 5.6, Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1, files `dbchangelog.xml` are the same. How I can run successful script on Ubuntu?

**EDIT**

All stacktrace:

```
    UTE database command: CREATE INDEX JOB_START_STATUS ON database.batch_job_execution(STATUS, START_TIME)
SEVERE 16.10.15 18:08: liquibase: /home/bok/Liquibase/dbchangelog.xml: /home/bok/Liquibase/dbchangelog.xml::1358761283019-16::royu: Change Set /home/bok/Liquibase/dbchangelog.xml::1358761283019-16::royu failed.  Error: Table 'database.batch_job_execution' doesn't exist [Failed SQL: CREATE INDEX JOB_START_STATUS ON database.batch_job_execution(STATUS, START_TIME)]
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'database.batch_job_execution' doesn't exist [Failed SQL: CREATE INDEX JOB_START_STATUS ON database.batch_job_execution(STATUS, START_TIME)]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:316)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:122)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1247)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1230)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:548)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:73)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:210)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:190)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1096)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:180)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:99)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'database.batch_job_execution' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2499)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:844)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:748)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:314)
    ... 12 more
DEBUG 16.10.15 18:08: liquibase: /home/bok/Liquibase/dbchangelog.xml::1358761283019-16::royu: Release Database Lock
DEBUG 16.10.15 18:08: liquibase: /home/bok/Liquibase/dbchangelog.xml::1358761283019-16::royu: Executing UPDATE database command: UPDATE database.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = 0, LOCKEDBY = NULL, LOCKGRANTED = NULL WHERE ID = 1
INFO 16.10.15 18:08: liquibase: /home/bok/Liquibase/dbchangelog.xml::1358761283019-16::royu: Successfully released change log lock
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Table 'database.batch_job_execution' doesn't exist [Failed SQL: CREATE INDEX JOB_START_STATUS ON database.batch_job_execution(STATUS, START_TIME)]

SEVERE 16.10.15 18:08: liquibase: /home/bok/Liquibase/dbchangelog.xml::1358761283019-16::royu: Table 'database.batch_job_execution' doesn't exist [Failed SQL: CREATE INDEX JOB_START_STATUS ON database.batch_job_execution(STATUS, START_TIME)]
liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set /home/bok/Liquibase/dbchangelog.xml::1358761283019-16::royu:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'database.batch_job_execution' doesn't exist [Failed SQL: CREATE INDEX JOB_START_STATUS ON database.batch_job_execution(STATUS, START_TIME)]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:584)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:73)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:210)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:190)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1096)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:180)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:99)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'database.batch_job_execution' doesn't exist [Failed SQL: CREATE INDEX JOB_START_STATUS ON database.batch_job_execution(STATUS, START_TIME)]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:316)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:122)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1247)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1230)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:548)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'database.batch_job_execution' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2499)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:844)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:748)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:314)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 0):

From the info given, it doesn't appear that the problem is platform specific, but rather that the changelog is trying to create an index on a table that doesn't exist.

Comment: I would check that the table exists in the schema/database/user you expect it to and that the user has permissions. The fact that the MySQL driver is reporting that it doesn't exist is a pretty strong indication. One other thing you could do is use the updateSQL command to generate the SQL and then either inspect it for mistakes or even just run it manually to see if you get the same results.